# Start an org file with all headers collapsed

Tags: org-mode

Whenever I open an org file, I want to see only the outline, so I want to have all the headers collapsed. I'm using doom emacs, this is what I have in my config.org file:

```el
(setq org-startup-folded "overview")
```

I also tried it like this:

```el
(after! org
(setq org-startup-folded "overview"))
```

Both of these do not work.

When I put this in the org file, it does work:

```org
#+STARTUP: overview
```

However, I want this setting to be global and not file specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the help is a little misleading on this one. You need to set `org-startup-folded` to `t`, not "overview":

```
(setq org-startup-folded t)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `customize-variable` interface to do this interactively (i.e., `M-x customize-variable org-startup-folded`).